# Loading html, css, javascript in sandbox preventing any communications

Tags: javascript, html, sandbox, content-security-policy, google-caja

Lets say I wish to execute a html/css/JS page disallowing any content being loaded from outside sources. Beyond that everything should be allowed.

## Some examples

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Clicking this link would somehow fail</a>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com">Would not load</iframe>
```

CSS

```
body{
  /* would show no background */
  background: url('http://www.google.com/google.jpg');
}
```

JavaScript

```
// Despite access-control-allow-origin: * being set on the external
// resource it would error out.
httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.allowscrosorigin.org/', true);

// Should not do anything
location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

---

I was hoping first that the `sandbox` attribute on `<iframe>`'s would allow this, but it turns out not to be able to do this. Next been looking into CSP, which I *think* would be able to get the CSS and AJAX part covered, but can't stop information from leaking through for example an iframed auto clicked link or `location.href`. So, are there any alternative ways to get this working all together? Or could this maybe be achieved with Google Caja (I would prefer not having to rewrite *everything* automatically, but if there are no other options then I am open to that as well)?

Comment: I was just going to suggest Google Caja.

Comment: @cspotcode So it should be able to do exactly this? If so I will definitely upvote (and lacking a better answer accept) any answer that can describe how one would need to set up Caja to prevent the very first item.

Comment: I'm actually not sure; I've never used Caja before.  However, it looks like Caja's uriPolicy does exactly what you want: https://developers.google.com/caja/docs/controllingnetwork/
It is apparently intended to control all network access: loading images, hyperlinks, XMLHttpRequests, etc.

Comment: @cspotcode Been playing in the sandbox, but I can't seem to stop it from allowing simple hyperlinks, though I am sure it must be possible as it is able to do the same thing for images.

Comment: Does it work in the "ES5/3 mode"?  I think the "ES5 mode (experimental)" mode is an experiment in using new features of ES5 to enforce secure code mashups at runtime without any code transformation, which means it doesn't do all the extensive server-side CSS and HTML transformations of the ES5/3 mode.

Comment: Caja definitely can prevent all external network access. The Playground site just doesn't allow this configuration. It's kind of outdated and we'd like to rebuild it but haven't done so yet. (The "Experimental" label is also outdated — please do NOT use ES5/3 mode for anything new.)